# Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, typescript

i am making a modal application in angular. i copied code from angular official site but this is not working my system.this code is working in plunker perfectly.Please tell me error thank in advance.

My app.module.ts file is this.

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { AppComponent, DialogOverviewExampleDialog } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  providers: [MatDialogRef],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My app.component file is this.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  animal: string;
  name: string;
  dialogRef: any;
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openDialog(): void {
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
    });

    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Please let me know where the problem occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `DialogOverviewExampleDialog` to `declarations` and `entryComponents` ([entry components](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components)).

```
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogOverviewExampleDialog
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DialogOverviewExampleDialog,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    MatDialogModule,
 ],
 providers: [MatDialogRef],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: yes, add `MatDialogModule` to `imports`. I'm going to update my answer. Please, provide the error you're getting.

Comment: Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?, ?, ?)
this error i got.

Comment: entryComponents is now depricated. This answer is still unresolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding the dependencies directly form the "ng add @angular/material", please make sure that you stop the running application and recompile the angular application, which will make the recently added dependencies available.